# Getting the max values, group it and then take the original count in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe is as follows,

```
df <- read.table(text="Name   value
A        0
                 A        1
                 A        2
                 A        3
                 B        0
                 B        0
                 B        3
                 C        5", header=T)

> df
  Name value
1    A     0
2    A     1
3    A     2
4    A     3
5    B     0
6    B     0
7    B     3
8    C     5
```

I initially want to assign bins to the maximum values of each name, therefore I did this,

```
p = df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(k =max(value))
p$values <- as.character(cut(p$k, breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10), labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10")))
```

And get the following output,

```
> p
Source: local data table [3 x 3]

    Name     k values
  (fctr) (int)  (chr)
1      A     3    2-3
2      B     3    2-3
3      C     5    4-5
```

Now I want to group it via values to see the bins split. Therefore I tried the following,

```
> p %>% group_by(values) %>% summarise(n())
Source: local data table [2 x 2]

  values   n()
   (chr) (int)
1    2-3     2
2    4-5     1
```

Now inside the 2-3 bins, the count is 2 and it is A & B. and inside 4-5 the count is 1 and C is behind it. Now I want to add another column to this output. The output should be the total rows of A and B in the original dataframe DF in first row and number of rows of C in the second row.

The output I am looking for is,

```
  values   n()   totalcount
   (chr) (int)
1    2-3     2       6
2    4-5     1       1
```

where 6 and 1 are number of rows inside the n() count. I am stuck up in creating this third column. Can anybody help me or give some advice to do this?

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't `totalcount` be `7` for `2-3` ?

Comment: I think @mtoto is right. Also, shouldn't `Name` `C` fall into the `5-10` category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do most of the assignments within the pipe (`%>%`).  For example, instead of `p$values <- ...`, use `mutate` to create a column of 'values'.  After grouping by 'values', we again `mutate` to create the 'n' so that the 'Name' column remains in the dataset which will be useful as a common variable to use in the `left_join` with original dataset ('df').    After, we `join`, use `summarise` to get the `first` value of 'n' and the number of rows ('totalcount') grouped by 'values'.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>%
   summarise(k=max(value)) %>% 
   mutate(values = cut(k, breaks= c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10), 
          labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10"))) %>% 
   group_by(values) %>%
   mutate(n=n()) %>% 
   left_join(., df, by ='Name') %>%
   group_by(values) %>%
   summarise(n=first(n), totalcount=n())
#  values     n totalcount
#   (fctr) (int)      (int)
#1    2-3     2          7
#2    4-5     1          1
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this kind of thing easier with `data.table`:

```
# convert to data table
library(data.table)             
dt <- data.table(df)

# find max by Name
p <- dt[, list(k=max(value)), by='Name']

# label maxes
breaks <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10)
labels <- c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10")
for (b in breaks) p[k==b, values:=labels[breaks==b]]

# count the Names within each bin
n <- p[, list(n=.N), by='values']

# count rows in original data table by bin
dt <- merge(dt, p, 'Name')
totalcount <- dt[, list(totalcount=.N), by='values']

# assemble n and totalcount to produce final output
n <- merge(n, totalcount, 'values')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another data.table implementation:

```
dt[, .(N=.N, value=max(value)), Name 
   ][, bin := cut(value,
                  breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10),
                  labels=c("0-1","1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-10"))
   ][, .(N=.N, NRows=sum(N)), bin
   ]
```